# Passing generic ToIntFunction to method in one line

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have a several `List`s of different objects and I want to map these Objects to an `int` value (Such as returning the length of a `String`) so I can perform operations in a `Stream`. So I create a method such as:

```
public <T> int foo(List<T> list, ToIntFunction<T> toInt) {
     return list.stream().mapToInt(toInt).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

(Note: `max` may be some other terminal operation)

Then I want to pass a `ToIntFunction` to it. I can do:

```
ToIntFunction<String> length = e -> e.length();
int bar = foo(list, length);
```

However I would have to write out the `ToIntFunction` every time I called the method.

Is there a way to just do something like:

```
foo(list, new ToIntFunction<String>(e -> e.length()) );  
//Obviously ToIntFunction is an interface and can't be instantiated
```

Or is it necessary to do it on two lines with a named variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass it as an inline lambda like so,

```
foo(Arrays.asList("test"), e -> e.length());
```

Or else here's the more readable method reference based approach,

```
foo(Arrays.asList("test"), String::length);
```

The trick here is that the `ToIntFunction<T>` is a single abstract method interface and the language allows you to create instances of these interfaces using lambda expressions.

Above lambda expression is just a syntactic sugar which substitutes more verbose anonymous inner class. Here's that pre-Java8 approach.

```
int bar = foo(Arrays.asList("test"), new ToIntFunction<String>() {
    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(String value) {
        return value.length();
    }
});
```